# query Prometheus HTTP API by list of metrics

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to query prometheus with a list of metric names in a single curl request.

There is a way to do it?

Something like this -

```
curl 'localhost:9090/api/v1/labels?name=<list_of_metric_names>'
```

I expect response like this -

```
[{
  metric_name:"metric1",
  labels:["label1", "label2"]
 },
 {
  metric_name:"metric2",
  labels:[..]
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endpoint `api/v1/labels` returns a combined list of label names. If this is acceptable, you can pass selector like `{__name__=~"metric1|metric2"}` to get them.

---

If you need list grouped by metric, you might use endpoint `api/v1/series`. It returns the list of time series matching selector (basically all the possible labels for every selected metric).

For example, command

```bash
curl -g 'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/series?' \
  --data-urlencode 'match[]=up{job="alertmanager"}' \
  --data-urlencode 'match[]=node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"}'
```

will return following json

```json
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":[
        {
            "__name__":"node_cpu_seconds_total",
            "cpu":"0",
            "env":"demo",
            "instance":"demo.do.prometheus.io:9100",
            "job":"node",
            "mode":"user"
        },
        {
            "__name__":"up",
            "env":"demo",
            "instance":"demo.do.prometheus.io:9093",
            "job":"alertmanager"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, you'll receive all possible combinations of label values, and will need to aggregate them.